# Connection between a symbol and its subscript form?

Tags: equation-solving, subscript

I have read all about subscript forms and that they are `DownValues` of `Subscript[]`. I still do not understand the following:

These all work fine and produce `True`:

```
Reduce[ForAll[t, Exists[Subscript[s, 1], t == Subscript[s, 1]]]]
Reduce[ForAll[Subscript[s, 2], 
    Exists[Subscript[s, 1], Subscript[s, 2] == Subscript[s, 1]]]]
Reduce[Exists[{s, Subscript[s, 1]}, s == Subscript[s, 1]]]
```

however this:

```
Reduce[ForAll[s, Exists[Subscript[s, 1], s == Subscript[s, 1]]]]
```

produces the error:

```
Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods
    available to Reduce.
```

I see similar behavior if instead of the subscript, I use: `OverHat[s]`.

Based on b3m2a1's comment, I switch the order of `s` and `Subscript[s, 1]`, and it indeed works (producing `True`):

```
Reduce[ForAll[Subscript[s, 1], Exists[s, s == Subscript[s, 1]]]]
```

There might be "nothing particularly deep going on," but I'd like to understand, if only to know what to avoid.

Another possible clue: the case that did *not* work above, after the error message, it repeated the input as:

```
Reduce[ForAll[s, s == Subscript[s, 1]]]
```

We see that the entire `Exists[Subscript[s, 1], ...]` part is gone, apparently `Reduce[]` logically discarded it. But this discards the "definition" of `Subscript[s, 1]` as well. It would seem that that is not okay, but discarding the definition of `s` would be okay. Does that make more sense? If so, please explain.

Any pointers would be most appreciated. Thanx.

Comment: I think you're just seeing the effect of when quantifiers are bound in `Reduce`... like all of the `True` examples allow the "Subscript-form" to effectively be replaced with a `Symbol` that is independent of `s` but the last example doesn't, although maybe it should. There's nothing particularly deep going on.

Comment: If you use `someSymbol` to represent a variable, never use a compound expression containing `someSymbol` to try to represent a different variable. That means that once you used `s` to denote something, you can't get away with also using `Subscript[s,1]` or `OverHat[s]` or `s[1]` because the system can't distinguish that from something like `f[s]` where `f` would represent some function.  It's safe to use both `Subscript[s,1]` and `Subscript[s,2]` but it is not safe to use one of these two together with a naked `s`.

Comment: I consider this a shortcoming of the design and generally avoid using `Subscript`. There are situations where it's useful though, e.g. when needing to generate a abritrary number of variables, we typically do `var[1], var[2], ...`. `Subscript[var,1], ...` would be just as good. But then don't use `var` on its own.